# Adding Rows to a DataGrid the Old-Fashioned Way (not binding)

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'd like to programmatically add rows to a DataGrid the old-fashioned way.  I have a very quick form I'd like to throw together with a couple of DataGrids in them and I am trying to add rows to them.  I don't want to use the MVVM binding pattern in this one situation because I want to keep the lines of code low.

I tried this but it is not working for me:

```
private static void FillGrid(DataGrid grid, IEnumerable<decimal> values)
{
    foreach (var item in values)
    {
        grid.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

The datagrid ends up with really small rows with no data in them.  It looks like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjn3B.png).  I also tried wrapping my values in a class and adding objects of that class to the DataGrid, but I got the same result.  Here's that code:

```
private class MyClass { public decimal MyDecimal { get; set; } }
private static void FillGrid(DataGrid grid, IEnumerable<decimal> values)
{
    foreach (var item in values)
    {
        grid.Items.Add(new MyClass() { MyDecimal = item });
    }
}
```

I have much more experience with Windows Forms.  I find MVVM binding tedious, overly-complicated, and difficult to debug.  How do I get this code to work?

Comment: You want to keep lines of code low so you are not using binding??  You already have a lot of code to not use binding and it is still not working.  How can you get less code then bind a collection and let DataGrid take care of presentation.

Comment: MVVM is not the only databinding pattern. Are you trying to avoid MVVM or all databinding? This seems kind of silly.

Comment: My first function is only five lines.  I wouldn't call that a lot of code.  I want to avoid creating a custom wrapper class with a public decimal field suitable for binding.  I also want to avoid using a BindingList or an ObservableCollection.  Further, I don't want to have to use a binding expression in the DataSource field of a DataGrid object in my XAML file.  I never get those right on the first try.  I want to just add a series decimals to the Items collection.

Comment: I can't count, I meant to say "seven lines", Four of which are only brackets. Let me emphasize that I use databinding in more substantial parts of my code. In this one case however, it's a window that will be displaying a small amount of data and has very little code in it. In this case, my code would hardly benefit from the use of databinding. I have some experience with databinding so I know it can be very robust. I don't need a robust solution though. I want something quick; something that can be debugged easily if needed. Regardless of this, I still don't know how to fix my code.

Comment: Can someone please explain why my question is being downvoted?  I asked a "practical, answerable question".  It concerned a problem that I actually face.  My post contained no misinformation and was not "egregiously sloppy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working, but you have to tell the `DataGrid` what to do with the data.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Unfortunately I haven't found a shorter way without binding.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.  I thought that I could use a DataGrid without having to use a Binding expression.  Apparently I can't.